# Trigger with filter

Tags: oracle, plsql

On Oracle 12c I need to create a trigger with filter. My filter is:

```
WHEN PERIOD <> FN_PERIODNEXT
```

where `FN_PERIODNEXT` is a function.

Following is the code for the trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AFTERIUDLIQUIDATIONSDETAILS
   BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE
   ON LIQUIDATIONSDETAILS
   FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (NEW.PERIODID <> FN_PERIODNEXT)
BEGIN
   IF INSERTING
   THEN
      UPDATE APPOINTSOFCAS
         SET INLD = INLD + 1
       WHERE     CUSTOMERID = :NEW.CUSTOMERID
             AND ID = :NEW.APPOINTOFCAID
             AND KINDCONTROLID = :NEW.KINDCONTROLID;
   END IF;

   IF DELETING
   THEN
      UPDATE APPOINTSOFCAS
         SET INLD = INLD - 1
       WHERE     CUSTOMERID = :OLD.CUSTOMERID
             AND ID = :OLD.APPOINTOFCAID
             AND KINDCONTROLID = :OLD.KINDCONTROLID;
   END IF;
END;
/
```

This fails to compile, with:

```
[Error] Compilation (8: 26): ORA-04076: invalid NEW or OLD specification
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: [Error] Compilation (8: 26): ORA-04076: invalid NEW or OLD specification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WHEN` clause is a `Boolean` expression that is evaluated by Oracle before the trigger’s body is executed. You need to change this line since its a syntax issue and hence not compiling.

```
WHEN (NEW.PERIOD <> OLD.FN_PERIODNEXT)
```

Now considering the fact that your FN_PERIODNEXT is a `Function`, then the above statement will `not work`. The above statememt evaluation only works on table columns.

In you scenario, you need to handle this condition within the body of your trigger as:

```
If FN_PERIODNEXT <> :NEW.PERIOD then
 . .
 ..
 ..
 End if;
```

So your trigger becomes like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AFTERIUDLIQUIDATIONSDETAILS
   BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE
   ON LIQUIDATIONSDETAILS
   FOR EACH ROW
   --WHEN (NEW.PERIODID <> FN_PERIODNEXT)
BEGIN
 If FN_PERIODNEXT <> :NEW.PERIOD 
  then

   IF INSERTING
   THEN
      UPDATE APPOINTSOFCAS
         SET INLD = INLD + 1
       WHERE     CUSTOMERID = :NEW.CUSTOMERID
             AND ID = :NEW.APPOINTOFCAID
             AND KINDCONTROLID = :NEW.KINDCONTROLID;
   END IF;

   IF DELETING
   THEN
      UPDATE APPOINTSOFCAS
         SET INLD = INLD - 1
       WHERE     CUSTOMERID = :OLD.CUSTOMERID
             AND ID = :OLD.APPOINTOFCAID
             AND KINDCONTROLID = :OLD.KINDCONTROLID;
   END IF;
 END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: now I take  this error: [Error] PLS-00201 (9: 27): PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.PERIODID' must be declared

Comment: Check out the column name. I guess you posted `PERIOD` wrongly as `PERIODID` in trigger definition and i copied it.

Comment: @XING You're missing the : in front of the NEW.PERIOD

Comment: Thanks Boneist, that was the second missing part,